# Same page PHP order form not working

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to build a simple email submit form for a newsletter. The user enters email address and the webmaster recieves their address as a form submit. The user must stay on the same page and maybe a Javascript box will be prompted with a thank you. I have this but it's not working:

```
<?php
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
  ?>
  <form name="contactform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

                    <input name="from" type="text" placeholder="Provide your e-mail address" class="newsletter_input" />
                    <input name="" type="submit" class="newsletter_submit" value="" />
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </form> 

                <?php
  }
else
  // the user has submitted the form
  {
  // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["from"]))
    {
    $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender

    mail("webmaster@example.com","From: $from\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: When you use the entered email address as the sender (From:) you risk it being classified as spam. I suggest setting your own email as the sender and putting the user email in the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of HTML does not look correct to me:

```
<input name="" type="submit" class="newsletter_submit" value="" />
```

You are missing the `name` attribute from this element. Because you are checking for `$_POST['submit']` being set, it should probably be:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="newsletter_submit" value="" />
```

without it, `!isset($_POST['submit'])` will always return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

In line 24 you should do some thing like this

```
  mail('webmaster@example.com', 'From', $from);
```

i hope it works!